# Compact subgroups of a topological group

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness, topological-groups

Consider  $G=(0,\infty )$ , with  the  metric  induced  by *Euclidean*  metric  from  $\mathbb R$ .$G$  is a  group  under  multiplication . Then  which  subgroups  of  it  are  compact  $?$

Now  $G=\mathbb R_+$  and  there  are   subgroups $\mathbb Z_+$,$\mathbb Q_+$, $\mathbb Q^c_+$ ;  none  of  which  is  compact  under  *Euclidean* metric .

The  compact  subsets of  $\mathbb R_+$  are  **:**

- Closed  intervals $[a,b]$- which  are  not  subgroups.
- Finite  sets $\{a_1,a_2,...,a_n\}$;$n\gt 1$ - which  are  also  not  subgroups.
- Singletons $\{b\}$ -  which  are  also  not  subgroups  except  $\{1\}$ .

So  $\{1\}$  is  the  only  subgroup  that  is  compact .

Is  this  correct  or   are  there  more  $?$

Thanks  for  any  help.

Comment: There are more compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}_+$ than that... $[1,2] \cup [3,4]$ is compact but not in your list. Besides a singleton is in particular a finite set.

Answer (score 4):

There are no non-trivial compact subrgroups of the group $G$, because each non-unit element $g\in G$ generates an unbounded subgroup $\langle g\rangle=\{g^n:n\in\Bbb Z\}$ which cannot be contained in a compact subset of the space $G$.

Comment: So  $1$  is  the  correct  answer  $?$

Comment: @user118494 Yes.